# Possible with multiple database connections

Tags: stored-procedures, linked-server, tsqlt

New to the tSQLt world (great tool set) and encountered a minor issue with a stored procedure I am setting up a test for.

If I for some reason have a stored procedure which connects to mutiple databases or even multiple SQL servers (Linked Servers).

Is it possible to do unit tests with tSQLt in such a scenario?

Comment: You can do anything that fits into the single transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented already, but I would like to add some more. So as I said already, that you can do anything that fits into the single transaction.

But for your case I would suggest to create synonyms for every cross database/instance object and then use synonyms everywhere.

I've created following function to mock view/tables synonyms. It has some limitations but at least it can handle simple use cases.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [tSQLt].[FakeSynonymTable] @SynonymTable VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
     BEGIN

         DECLARE @NewName VARCHAR(MAX)= @SynonymTable+REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(100)), '-', '');
         DECLARE @RenameCmd VARCHAR(MAX)= 'EXEC sp_rename '''+@SynonymTable+''', '''+@NewName+''';';

        EXEC tSQLt.SuppressOutput
              @RenameCmd;

        DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT * INTO '+@SynonymTable+' FROM '+@NewName+' WHERE 1=2;';

        EXEC (@sql);

        EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable
              @TableName = @SynonymTable;
     END;
```

Comment: Great, thanks
I have a few extra questions related to distributed transactions but they are out of scope as I see it

Answer (score 1):

Without you providing sample code I am not certain of your exact use case but this information may help.

The alternative approach for cross-database testing (assuming both databases are on the same instance) is to install tSQLt in both databases.  Then you can mock the objects in the remote database in the same way that you would if they were local.

E.g. If you had a stored procedure in LocalDb that referenced a table in RemoteDb, you could do something like this:

Imagine you have a procedure that selects a row from a table called localTable in the local database and inserts that row in to a table called remoteTable in the remote database (on the same instance)

```
create procedure [myTests].[test mySproc inserts remoteTable from local table]
as
begin
    -- Mock the local table in the local database
    exec tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.localTable' ;
    -- Mock the remote table (not the three part object reference to remoteDb)
    exec RemoteDb.tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.remoteTable' ;

    --! Data setup ommitted

    --! exec dbo.mySproc @param = 'some value' ;

    --! Get the data from the remote table into a temp table so we can test it
    select * into #expected from RemoteDb.dbo.remoteTable;

    --! Assume we have already populated #actual with our expected results
    exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable '#expected', '#actual' ;
end
```

The above code demonstrates the basics but I blogged about this in more detail some years ago [here](http://datacentricity.net/2011/12/advanced-database-unit-testing-with-tsqlt-testing-cross-database-tables/).

Unfortunately this approach will not work across linked servers,

Comment: Thanks, yes sorry for being a bit vaqueu  
I have configured the test project as outlined in this blog:  
https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/setting-up-ssdt-database-projects-and-tsqlt/  

Basically you have two database projects, one for the actual implementation and an extra project for the test cases.  

tSQLt needs to be installed in the development database and added to the test project which created a new database with tSQLt and test cases once test project is published  

Using synomyms should work with this approach