# How to Fake tables from other database in tsqlt?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I have a stored Procedure in "Database A" for which I am trying to write SQL Unit Test using tsqlt, The stored procedure uses tables from "Database B and Database c" as well from the same server. What is the syntax to Fake tables from different databases? Thanks in Advance

I have tried this, EXEC RemoteDB.tsqlt.FakeTable @tablename = TableA
But its not working

Comment: you can create synonyms for these objects and then create something like I proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708116/possible-with-multiple-database-connections

Comment: If you have installed tSQLt on the RemoteDB then your example should work. What error do you get?

Comment: I @Peter , I have Installed tSQLt on the RemoteDB as well. But, getting the following error : Database 'RemoteDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. Note( Both the DB's are on the Same server)

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. The error is telling that you've misspelled the db name

Comment: The error is shown for the Keyword "RemoteDB", Other than that the Database name mentioned is correct