# Rollback Error in tsqlt while executing tsqlt tests

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt

Help me solve this error in tsqlt. `

I tried to create fake synonyms and getting the following error

```
> (Error) An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure
> 'sp_addextendedproperty'.[16,2]{sys.sp_addextendedproperty,37} (There
> was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no
> corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.{tSQLt.Private_RunTest,160})
```

Do I need to have **try catch** inside my test stored Procedure?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server and tSQLt are you on? Have you tried reinstalling tSQLt?

Comment: You can't fake synonyms. Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708116/possible-with-multiple-database-connections, this functions works quite well in my case.

Comment: drop extendedproperty and try again